# How to flag end of loop over dictionary with two int's tuple as key - combination-like loop needed

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

i have in memory a dictionary with the following pattern:

```
value_refs[tuple([a,b])] = some float value
```

the dictionary is a pool of all the possible combinations of the values of 4000 references, previously computated (some millions).
ex:

```
...
value_refs[1,4] =0,76543
value_refs[1,5] =0,89734 #i want this value, since it is the bigger of all the second ref's,
                         # related with the ref. 1 (first tuple in the key)
...
value_refs[1,4000] =0,77543
...
...
value_refs[4000,30] =0,76543
value_refs[4000,31] =1,89734 # I want this value, since it is the bigger of all the second
                             # references, related with the ref. 4000 (first tuple in the key)
value_refs[4000,32] =0,77543
```

The problem is that i don't know how to make a loop over the entire dictionary keys in the same mode as 'combinations' do, using them as iterables, like:

```
asymptote=0
cache=[]
pool_chain={}

for c in value_refs.keys()[c][0]: # [0] because i need the first tuple value of the key, by rank
    for d in value_refs.keys()[d][1]: # [1] because i need a loop over the range of all the second
                                    #tuple values in the dict pool, versus the outer loop
        while True:
            try:
                if value_refs[c,d] > asymptote:
                    cache=[c,d]
                    asymptote=value_refs[c,d]
            except KeyError:
                pass
            except StopIteration:
                pool_chain[cache]=asymptote
                asymptote=0
        #and now c would advance by an ordered rank intil the number 4000...
```

I know that the above code doesn't work, because of bad syntax but i think that is the best way to post the question. The unordered nature of the dictionaries in python is (i think) a problem to that nested loops process the 2-tuple keys by an ordered way, like 1,2, 1,3 ... 1,4000 2,3 2,4 and so on. How can i iterate over my dictionary in memory in an ordered way (by rank) and extract both the 2-tuple key and the value that is the biggest for the second value in the key versus the first tuple-value in the same key, and this for all combinations? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your life would be much easier if you redesign the `value_refs` to a `dict of dicts`. That way you may easily reference `value_refs[first_key]` or iterate through the first keys.

Answer (score 0):

How about a 2D-array with 4000*4000 elements? Takes less memory and is faster then such a dict. Especially, if you have **all the possible combinations**.

Have a look at [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/).

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.empty((4000,4000))
for i, a in enumerate([...]):
    for j, b in enumerate([...]):
        arr[i, j] = ...

...

for i in arr.shape[0]:
    for j in arr.shape[1]:
        ... arr[i, j]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is collect the max value for the first value for each unique key pair.

Here is one approach:

```
from collections import defaultdict

all_values = defaultdict(list)

keys = value_refs.keys()

for k in keys:
   all_values[k[0]].append(value_ref[k])

for k,v in all_values.iteritems():
   print i,max(v)
```

Comment: It is possible to track how is the correspondent 2nd tuple in the 'keys' variable to the respective maximum value? Thanks?